# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-conversion

I need to transform 140 .docx files into txt. I am using the following Python code that I found here in StackOverflow.

I tried this:

```
import os
from docx import Document

# Path to the folder containing .docx files
input_folder = "C:/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/word"

# Path to the folder where .txt files will be saved
output_folder = "C:/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/Txt"

# Get a list of all .docx files in the input folder
files = [f for f in os.listdir(input_folder) if f.endswith(".docx")]

# Loop through each .docx file and convert it to .txt
for file in files:
    docx_path = os.path.join(input_folder, file)
    txt_path = os.path.join(output_folder, os.path.splitext(file)[0] + ".txt")

    doc = Document(docx_path)
    content = [p.text for p in doc.paragraphs]

    with open(txt_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as txt_file:
        txt_file.write("\n".join(content))

print("Conversion complete!")
```

But whenever I run the code, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 2
      1 import os
----> 2 from docx import Document
      4 # Path to the folder containing .docx files
      5 input_folder = "C:/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/word"

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\docx.py:30
     27 except ImportError:
     28     TAGS = {}
---> 30 from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning
     31 from warnings import warn
     33 import logging

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'
```

Do you know why am I getting this error and how could I solve this? Thank you!

Comment: There is a need for a specific module here. Check the list of the installed modules by running `pip list` or `pip3 list` (depending on what you are using) in the command line to see if `exceptions` appears.

Comment: did you perform `pip install python-docx` ?

Comment: Thanks both! It was that problem. I forgot to pip install python-docx.  Now it's all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error can occur for multiple reasons:

> Not having the python-docx package installed by running `pip install python-docx`.

> Installing the package in a different Python version than the one you're using.

> Installing the package globally and not in your virtual environment.

> Your IDE running an incorrect version of Python.

> Naming your module exception.py which would shadow the official module.

> Declaring a variable named exceptions which would shadow the imported variable.

See this answer: [https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-exceptions#:~:text=The%20Python%20%22ModuleNotFoundError%3A%20No%20module,pip%20install%20python%2Ddocx%20command](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-no-module-named-exceptions#:%7E:text=The%20Python%20%22ModuleNotFoundError%3A%20No%20module,pip%20install%20python%2Ddocx%20command).

Comment: Thanks! Now it works.  forgot to pip install python-docx.